# Sequelize classMethods vs instanceMethods

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

So starting my adventure into all things Node. One of the tools I am trying to learn is Sequelize. So I will start off what I was trying to do:

```js
'use strict';
var crypto = require('crypto');

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    first_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    last_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    salt: DataTypes.STRING,
    hashed_pwd: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {

    },
    instanceMethods: {
      createSalt: function() {
        return crypto.randomBytes(128).toString('base64');
      },
      hashPassword: function(salt, pwd) {
        var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', salt);

        return hmac.update(pwd).digest('hex');
      },
      authenticate: function(passwordToMatch) {
        return this.hashPassword(this.salt, passwordToMatch) === this.hashed_pwd;
      }
    }
  });
  return User;
};
```

I am confused on when to use `classMethods` vs `instanceMethods`. To me when I think about `createSalt()` and `hashPassword()` should be class methods. They are general and for the most part dont really have anything to do with the specific instance they are just used in general. But when I have `createSalt()` and `hashPassword()` in `classMethods` I cannot call them from `instanceMethods`.

I have tried variations of the following:

```
this.createSalt();
this.classMethods.createSalt();
createSalt();
```

Something like below wont work and I am probably just not understanding something simple.

```
authenticate: function(passwordToMatch) {
  console.log(this.createSalt());
  return this.hashPassword(this.salt, passwordToMatch) === this.hashed_pwd;
}
```

Any hints/tips/direction would be very much so appreciated!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

All the method who don't modify or check any type of instance should be `classMethod` and the rest `instanceMethod`

ex:

```js
// Should be a classMethods
function getMyFriends() {
  return this.find({where{...}})
}

// Should be a instanceMethods
function checkMyName() {
  return this.name === "george";
}
```

Comment: That makes sense to me and thats what I kind of figured so general functions such as makeSalt() and hashPassword() should be class methods because they really have nothing to do with the specific instance. SO that said now my real problem I guess is not being able to call a classMethond inside my instanceMethod and not sure what the deal is.

Comment: I got on the IRC and they were able to help me out. Its a bit different then I am use too in other languages but thats just part of the learning process! since its a class method it becomes just part of the model so you dont have to use something like "this." you just call it like "User.getSalt()" so its all working now as I would have expected!

Comment: I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Although the basics are that `instance` methods should be used when you want to modify your `instance` ( ergo row ). I would rather not pollute the `classMethods` with methods that don't use the `class` ( ergo the table ) itself.

In your example I would put `hashPassword` function outside your class and leave it as a helper function somewhere in my utilities module ( or why not the same module but as a normal defined function ) ... like

```
var hashPassword = function(...) { ... }

...

...

  instanceMethods: { 
     authenticate: function( ... ) { hashPassword( ... ) }
  }
```

Comment: I wondered about doing that as well. I think I will go ahead and do it just to get in the habit of doing so. I couldn't decide if it made since to separate it or not since I will only use hashPassword within the User model.

Answer (score 1):

I found this worked for me as of sequelize 3.14

```
var myModel = sequelize.define('model', {

}, {
  classMethods: {
    someClassMethod: function() {
      return true;
    }
}, {
  instanceMethods: {
    callClassMethod: function() {
      myModel.someClassMethod();
    }
  }
});
```