# Error: Unrecognized data type for field classMethods

Tags: javascript, database, sequelize.js

When using the following model definition:

```
var address = connection.define('address', {
    id : {
        type :sequelize.INTEGER ,
        primaryKey : true ,
        autoIncrement : true
    },
    content : sequelize.TEXT ,
    classMethods : {
        associate : function(model){
            var user  = model.user; 
            user.hasMany(address);
        }
    }
});
```

I am unable to debug the: `Error: Unrecognized data type for field classMethods`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly you have mixed the model definition part and other options part. Look at the examples like [Sequelize classMethods vs instanceMethods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34258938/sequelize-classmethods-vs-instancemethods), they should be in two objects, as two seperate arguments.

Therefore, your code should at least be modified to something like:

```
var address = connection.define('address', {
    id: {
        type: sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    content: sequelize.TEXT
},
// <-- here, another object / argument started
{
    classMethods: {
        associate: function (model) {
            var user = model.user;
            user.hasMany(address);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah I figured that out .Thanks for the answer !

Answer (score 1):

i missed the bracket and face this issue

```
'use stri

ct';

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var category = sequelize.define('category', {
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        image_url: DataTypes.STRING,
        thumb_url: DataTypes.STRING,
        type1: {
            type: DataTypes.ENUM,
            values: ['public_services', 'local_services']
        }
    }//this one, 



{//this bracket
            classMethods: {
                associate: function(models) {
                    // associations can be defined here
                    //   category.hasMany(models.directory, [{foreignKey:'dir_fid'}])
                }
            }
        });
        return category;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var address = connection.define('address',{
    id:{
        type :sequelize.INTEGER ,
        primaryKey : true ,
        autoIncrement : true
    },
    content : sequelize.TEXT
    },
    {
        classMethods : {
            associate : function(model){
                var user  = model.user; 
                user.hasMany(address);
            }
        }
    }

);
```

^^Syntax Issue